# Scroll button for overflow image

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have an image that has overflow hidden applied to it but what i would like is to have a scroll button that on click scrolls to the bottom of the image slowly.

```css
.img-holder {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-holder">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x600">
</div>
```

Is this possible?

Thank you

Comment: Should be... Did you try something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```js
$('.scroll-button').on('click', function(){
  var imgBox = $(this).next('.img-holder');
  imgBox.animate({
      scrollTop: imgBox.children('img').outerHeight(true)
  }, 2000);
});
```

```css
.img-holder {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: auto;
}

.scroll-button {
  cursor:pointer;
}

.scroll-button:hover {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="scroll-button">Click to scroll</span>
<div class="img-holder">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x600">
</div>
```

This should also work with multiple image Boxes. All you need to do is the same markup as shown in the example.

Comment: This is perfect thanks very much. Im guessing i can just reverse this to have a scroll back to the top option once it reaches the bottom. Will have a play with jquery. Thanks again

Comment: @rufus yes to scroll backup just set scrollTop to 0 inside the animate so just replace the scrollTop... with : `scrollTop: 0` happy coding

Comment: thanks @caramba for all your help. I'm just a little confused where to add the scroll up inside the animate. i apologies my jquery skills are pretty basic

Comment: @rufus it depends, you should put it where you want it :) see this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/wuy645b1/ now you click on the same button, once the scroll position is bigger 0 it scrolls back up ...

Comment: thank you so much, i kind of understand the syntax which i am working through to understand how you did it. It works great so thanks again for your kind help

Answer (score 1):

Yes! It is possible to add a button at the end of the image to scroll the page.
Use the code as follows:

```js
var currentScrollPosition = 0;
$('.button').on('click', function () {
    currentScrollPosition += 50;
    $('.img-holder').animate({
          scrollTop: currentScrollPosition
    });
});
```

```css
.img-holder {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: auto;
}
.button {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="img-holder">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x600">
</div>
<button class="button">Scroll down</button>
</body>
```

Comment: This is great thanks for your help much appreciated!